# Remove string from file name to leave variable?

Tags: bash, text-processing, rename

I have the following list of files:

```
Dorn_Triatomine_A5201_sequence_1_unmappedforTdim_tdim.alleles.tsv
Dorn_Triatomine_A5201_sequence_1_unmappedforTdim_tdim.matches.tsv
Dorn_Triatomine_A5201_sequence_1_unmappedforTdim_tdim.snps.tsv
Dorn_Triatomine_A5201_sequence_1_unmappedforTdim_tdim.tags.tsv
Dorn_Triatomine_T9252_sequence_1_unmappedforTdim_tdim.alleles.tsv
Dorn_Triatomine_T9252_sequence_1_unmappedforTdim_tdim.matches.tsv
Dorn_Triatomine_T9252_sequence_1_unmappedforTdim_tdim.snps.tsv
Dorn_Triatomine_T9252_sequence_1_unmappedforTdim_tdim.tags.tsv
```

I would like to eliminate some of the repetitive string and rename the file as follow:

```
A5201_tdim.alleles.tsv
A5201_tdim.matches.tsv
A5201_tdim.snps.tsv
```

I tried using:

```
mv Dorn_Triatomine_*_sequence_1_unmappedforTdim_tdim.tags.tsv *_tdim.tags.tsv
```

What would be the simplest way to achieve this task?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This script ought to do it:

```
#!/bin/sh
for f in Dorn_Triatom* ; do
  mv "$f" `echo "$f" | sed -e 's/Dorn_Triatomine_//' -e 's/sequence_1_unmappedforTdim_//'`
done
```

Comment: NB I assume the two strings after s/ are the ones you want to remove

Comment: Please note that it would give an error if there is no file starts with Dorn_Triatom and placing $f inside of double quotes would be safer in case of spaces in file names.

Comment: @LuciaO if this is what works for you please remember to _accept_ the answer with the tick mark.

Answer (score 0):

Using `grep` with PCRE to get the new file name:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
for file in *.tsv; do
  newname="$(grep -Po '^[^_]*_[^_]*_\K[^_]*_'<<<"$file")$(grep -Po '.*_\K.*$' <<<"$file")"
  mv "$file" "$newname"
done
```

`newname` is combined of output of two `grep` operations:

- `grep -Po '^[^_]*_[^_]*_\K[^_]*_'<<<"$file"` will output the `A5201_` like strings from each filename
- `$(grep -Po '.*_\K.*$' <<<"$file")` will match the last portion of the filename, after last `_`
- `$()` is the `bash` command substitution pattern.